# Jetty 8 as a service using java service wrapper.on windows

Tags: jetty, java-service-wrapper

I am trying to setup jetty as a service using JavaServiceWrapper 3.5.16 and I have tried all the four integration methods specified at the [JSW website](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html!), but still I am facing this problem:

I do exactly as the documentation for JSW says and configure the `wrapper.conf` file, I start the `jetty.bat` file and it shows that jetty has been started. But when I try to access it from the browser, I get

> 404 not found error

Also , when jetty supposedly starts it doesn't deploy any of the .war files in the webapps folder.

I configured the `wrapper.conf` as follows for the 4th integration method(WrapperJarApp):

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%WRAPPER_HOME%/lib/*.jar

wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JETTY_HOME%/lib/*.jar

wrapper.java.classpath.3=%JETTY_HOME%/start.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%WRAPPER_HOME%/lib
```

What should I change in the configuration for jetty to start properly and deploy the files in the webapp folder.

Please help!!

edit:
`wrapper log file content`-

STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 13:43:55 | --> Wrapper Started as Console

STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 13:43:55 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.16
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 13:43:55 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 13:43:55 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 13:43:55 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 13:43:55 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 13:43:56 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 13:43:56 | 2012-11-20 13:43:56.762:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.3.v20120416
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 13:43:57 | 2012-11-20     13:43:56.965:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:Enabled Protocols [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 13:43:57 | 2012-11-20     13:43:56.965:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SslSocketConnector@0.0.0.0:7443
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 13:43:57 | 2012-11-20    13:43:56.996:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8085

`wrapper.conf`-

```
    #encoding=UTF-8
# Configuration files must begin with a line specifying the encoding
#  of the the file.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Professional and Standard Editions of the Wrapper require a valid
#  License Key to start.  Licenses can be purchased or a trial license
#  requested on the following pages:
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
##include.debug

# The Wrapper will look for either of the following optional files for a
#  valid License Key.  License Key properties can optionally be included
#  directly in this configuration file.
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

# The following property will output information about which License Key(s)
#  are being found, and can aid in resolving any licensing problems.
#wrapper.license.debug=TRUE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Localization
#********************************************************************
# Specify the locale which the Wrapper should use.  By default the system
#  locale is used.
#wrapper.lang=en_US # en_US or ja_JP

# Specify the location of the Wrapper's language resources.  If these are
#  missing, the Wrapper will default to the en_US locale.
wrapper.lang.folder=../lang

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=/java/path
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp 

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%JETTY_HOME%/lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JETTY_HOME%/start.jar


# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%JETTY_HOME%/lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djetty.home=%JETTY_HOME%
#wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp 

# Java Additional Parameters from File
wrapper.java.additional_file=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
# wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Do not start if the pid file already exists.
wrapper.pidfile.strict=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Test Wrapper Sample Application

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=10
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
# (Ignore output from dumping the configuration to the console.  This is only needed by the TestWrapper sample application.)
wrapper.filter.trigger.999=wrapper.filter.trigger.*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.999=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.999=NONE
#  Ignore -verbose:class output to avoid false positives.
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=[Loaded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1000=NONE
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1001=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1001=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1001=The JVM has run out of memory.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Email Notifications. (Requires Professional Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Common Event Email settings.
#wrapper.event.default.email.debug=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.host=<SMTP_Host>
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.port=25
#wrapper.event.default.email.subject=[%WRAPPER_HOSTNAME%:%WRAPPER_NAME%:%WRAPPER_EVENT_NAME%] Event Notification
#wrapper.event.default.email.sender=<Sender email>
#wrapper.event.default.email.recipient=<Recipient email>

# Configure the log attached to event emails.
#wrapper.event.default.email.attach_log=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.lines=50
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.format=LPTM
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.loglevel=INFO

# Enable specific event emails.
#wrapper.event.wrapper_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_prelaunch.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_started.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_deadlock.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stop.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stopped.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_failed_invocation.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_max_failed_invocations.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_kill.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_killed.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_unexpected_exit.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.wrapper_stop.email=TRUE

# Specify custom mail content
wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email.body=The JVM was restarted.\n\nPlease check on its status.\n

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=testwrapper

# Display name of the service
wrapper.displayname=Test Wrapper Sample Application

# Description of the service
wrapper.description=Test Wrapper Sample Application Description

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START, DELAY_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

wrapper.ntservice.name=jetty
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=jetty deployment Server
wrapper.ntservice.description=jetty deployment Server
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is the value of wrapper.app.parameter.1 in your conf file?

I'd suggest the following configuration:

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp    
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%JETTY_HOME%/lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JETTY_HOME%/start.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%JETTY_HOME%/lib    
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djetty.home=%JETTY_HOME%
#not necessary on windows 
#wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp    
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main
```

Hope this helps you out.

Edit: in my jetty home dir, the wrapper binary is in the bin folder and libwrapper.so (wrapper.dll) and wrapper.jar in the lib directory. So I don't have WRAPPER_HOME set...

Comment: Hi Tanuki,

I tried the configuration that you suggested (existing config was almost same) but i get the same result. the cmd prompt shows that it has started the jetty server but i am not able to access it from browser nor is it deploying any of the webapps. link to snapshot: (http://i.stack.imgur.com/cNawZ.png)

Comment: @r3ap3r did you make sure that the classpath is exactly as in my configuration?  when I used your classpath, especially wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JETTY_HOME%/lib/*.jar was causing the error you described. so I assume some classes were colliding...

Comment: yes.. i used the same configuration which you had mentioned in your solution..didn't work :(.

Comment: @r3ap3r hi, is the error message you are seeing in your browser still 404? could you also please post your current log and conf file?

Comment: @r3ap3r on Windows, wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp should not be set, therefore please remove this line from your conf file

Comment: @tanuki.. i have posted my logs and conf file ..please refer the edit section of my question..i was still seeing 404 on browser after trying your config.

Comment: @r3ap3r your wrapper.java.additional properties are not correct, please correct to exactly what it is in my answer and then retry

Comment: yes i have edited my config to match yours and have tried again but still it shows 404 not found and none of the .war files in webapps folder run

Comment: @r3ap3r, wrapper.java.additional.1 is also incorrect... please correct this one as well

Comment: one more question.. how should the properties be specified in wrapper.conf if the environment variable contains spaces in the path, should they be specified via command line explicitly within double quotes?

Comment: Yep. Setting `jetty.home` fixed it for me too: it works without `jetty.home` if I just run `java -jar start.jar`, but with JSW Jetty8 simply failed to find any webapps. Exceptionally frustrating experience, because you get *nothing* googlable. Not sure whether it's Jetty's fault or JSW's, but in any case, Tanuki, a guide on your website like the one for JBoss would help massively!

Answer (score 1):

Starting Jetty also works with the WrapperStartStopApp integration method.
This is my wrapper.conf for my jetty/solr Server:

```
set.WRAPPER_HOME=D:/solr/solr_server4.1/service
set.JAVA_HOME=D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_29
set.TMP=C:/TEMP

wrapper.working.dir=%WRAPPER_HOME%/..
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStopApp

wrapper.java.classpath.1=%WRAPPER_HOME%/lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%WRAPPER_HOME%/../start.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%WRAPPER_HOME%/lib

wrapper.java.additional.1=-Xmx1g
#wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.io.tmpdir=%TMP%

# StartStopApp START
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.2=0

# StartStopApp STOP
wrapper.app.parameter.3=org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.4=TRUE
wrapper.app.parameter.5=1
wrapper.app.parameter.6=--stop
```

With a start.ini containing for example

```
STOP.PORT=8990
STOP.KEY=mysecretkey
```