# How to deploy a .war to Embedded Jetty of Gridgain

Tags: gridgain

I would like to deploy my custom web application (.war) to the embedded Jetty container of Gridgain. Would you please direct me to documentation or describe steps?
Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GridGain embedded Jetty server was not intended to run user war applications, so there is no explicit logic for war file deployment.

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011940/how-to-configure-a-webapps-deployment-directory-in-jetty) question, you might be able to deploy a war file by specifying `$JETTY_HOME` environment variable and dropping your war file to appropriate folder.